# Want to echo specific value from json data

Tags: php

```
{"data":{"tokenId":"cbad508f88a2a8ff47c75426338026de"},"success":true,"error":{"errorCode":"200","errorMsg":"successfully"}}
{"referredBy":"Dvbrhhv","deviceId":"488014664955832","msisdn":"8358808909"}
```

And I want to echo only tokenId from this data in php how can i initiate kindly help me out

Comment: decode your json. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1):

Your `json` is not `valid json` please check your json on [this link](http://pro.jsonlint.com/)

```
$json='{
    "data": {
        "tokenId": "cbad508f88a2a8ff47c75426338026de"
    },
    "success": true,
    "error": {
        "errorCode": "200",
        "errorMsg": "successfully"
    }
}';

$json=json_decode($json);
echo $json->data->tokenId;
```

use `json_decode` [Demo](https://eval.in/478709)

Answer (score 0):

You can get it

```
$jsonResult = json_decode($json ,true);
echo $jsonResult['data']['tokenId'];
```

You can see [result](https://eval.in/478713)

```
<br/>
```

output : cbad508f88a2a8ff47c75426338026de